# Audio element and react-player not working on iPhone mobile

Tags: reactjs, iphone, audio, mobile, react-player

I am working with an app that I have placed in cloud. The web version of the app works nicely with Windows Desktop and Android mobile and even Mac Desktop but **fails to play both audio element and video (react-player) with iPhone mobile**.

The audio element start button is displayed, but clicking the button does not start the audio. Nothing seems to happen on click.

```
    const [audioPlayer, setAudioPlayer] = useState<HTMLAudioElement | undefined>(undefined)

    const playRecordedNote = async () => {
        const audio = new Audio(audioUrl)
        audio.muted = false
        audio.autoplay = true
        await audio.play()
        audio.addEventListener('ended', audioEndedActions)
        setAudioPlayer(audio)
    }
```

In place of the video there is just a black view with a white "play" icon with a strikethrough line. Nothing happens on click.

```
        <ReactPlayer
            url={videoUrl}
            controls={true}
            width='100%'
            height='100%'
            onEnded={() => console.log('ended')}
            playsinline={true}
            onError={(error) => console.log(error)}
        />
```

Is there a way to listen to audio elements and play videos in iPhone mobile web app?

Answer (score 1):

I also face the similar issue, but it's worked for me when we set the volume of player to zero or muted=true as for iphone browser can't control the volume  via js

Hope this would resolve your issue